# What is the behaviour of \fontsize if baselineskip is below a certain value?

Tags: fontsize, vertical-spacing, baseline

during my optimization process I found something spurious I cannot explain to myself and which I would like to understand. So with `\fontsize` you set the fontsize and the baselineskip. However the behaviour of the second paramater is a bit unclear to me, because if you reduce it too much, at a certain point the baselineskip gets bigger again. Let me show you my example:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1]
    \columnbreak
    
    \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1]
    \columnbreak
    
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1]
    \columnbreak
    
    \fontsize{10}{8}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1]
    \columnbreak
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this, your result will be looking like this:

[image]

Now from the first to the third column it seems logic, that the baselineskip is reduced and hence less space is needed vertically to typeset. But with the third column, even though the baselineskip is reduced even further, it needs more vertical space overall. It is strange however, that for example from line 11 to 12 (starting with tus and lum), the spacing seems to be narrower than in column 3, while in a lot of line the spacing is bigger. Changing the baselineskip to lower values down to 0 does not modify the vertical alignment further.

What is the purpose of this behaviour and is it intended? I cannot see a benefit of this and I am a bit confused.

Comment: `\fontsize` isn't really involved here other than it sets `\baselineskip`, this is the TeX-primitive behaviour of vertical mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

If you add

```
 \lineskiplimit = -\maxdimen
```

you get the above.

TeX tries to maintain an even baseline spacing, as set by `\baselineskip` (which is set by the second argument of `\fontsize` and other places). However normally if the text in the lines is too large (say an inline math fraction) you do not want to maintain the even spacing and over-print the surrounding lines, so if the space that needs to be added gets below `\lineskiplimit` TeX gives up even spacing and just inserts the fixed space `\lineskip` between the lines.  By default `\lineskip` is 1pt and `\lineskiplimit` is 0pt.

By setting a suitable large negative value for `\lineskiplimit` you can force even spacing even at the expense of over-printing.

In the last column you can see:

[image]

Comment: thanks for that explanation. What I don't get from it, taken my example: You say TeX adds `\lineskip=1pt` in those lines that are below `\lineskiplimit`, right? So if I am setting `\baselineskip=8pt` through `\fontsize{10}{8}`, my understanding would be that the vertical spacing could never be more than with 9pt baselineskip? What am I overlooking?

Comment: @TobiBS if you set baselineskip to 8pt but then insert a 5 row inline math matrix (or a `\large` accented capital or whatever) then (for normal values of \lineskiplimit) `\baselineskip` is ignored, fixed glue of `\lineskip (1pt) is added and then the box with the over-size line is added at its natural height. People do this all the time adding lareg images, then don't expect them to overlap and be laid down at 12pt intervals, they expect them to come one below the other.

Comment: @TobiBS also there is (for a reason I never understood, there is another answer on site discussing this) a discontinuity in that latex, following plain tex sets `\lineskiplimit` at 0pt but `\lineskip` at 1pt, so if the text _just_ fits in at 9pt spacing that will be allowed even if it is only adding .0001pt glue between the lines, but if you ask for 8pt then that will trigger `\lineskip` so even line spacing is abandoned, so you get the natural height lines (around 9pt) plus 1pt \lineskip padding so more like 10pt total.

Comment: @TobiBS one of these probably says something relevant:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1090+%5Clineskiplimit

Comment: Is it possible to set `\lineskiplimit = -\maxdimen` and then trigger a warning, everytime LaTeX detects a clash of glyphs?

Comment: @TobiBS no, you could look in the log and see if negative spacing has been applied, but latex has no idea if the descenders on one line actually overlap with tall characters on the next, so if you set `\showoutput` and look in the log you will see negative baselineskip added but you can not tell (and tex can not tell you) that the g actually hits the ll in that zoomed in example, just that it could potentially hit, if the wording is changed slightly the ll would miss the g.