# How to enforce a consistent line height independent of font/glyph size

Tags: fonts, fontspec, line-spacing

I'm using XeLaTex to load multiple TrueType fonts using `fontspec`'s `\newfontfamily`. I want to keep a fixed line height throughout the document, let's say 16pt, even if I switch fonts or font sizes. The main but not only reason is that this is a 2-column layout and I want the lines match up in both cols.

When I use a font at a typical font size, this works fine:

`\fontsize{12pt}{16pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}`

When I use a smaller font size, this works fine, too and XeLaTeX adds extra space between the lines to enforce the lineheight:

`\fontsize{8pt}{16pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}`

However if I use a font size close to or larger than the line height, depending on the font, the glyph heights seem to take precedence over the line height, making the text/paragraph higher:

`\fontsize{16pt}{16pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}`

How can I enforce the 16pt line height at the risk of lines/glypes overlapping (like in CSS)?

Comment: as always: it is much easier to answer such a question if there is code to test. But beside this, look for lineskip, lineskiplimit, nointerlineskip.

Comment: set `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` (there was a question about this in the last few days)

Comment: you don't need to say `plus 0pt minus 0pt`  (although it does no harm)

Comment: I didn't find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549218/what-is-the-behaviour-of-fontsize-if-baselineskip-is-below-a-certain-value/549219 as I was looking for different keywords. Please mark as duplicate, that solves the issue!